# Gates and energy loss

Tags: logic-gates, cpu, energy

i read in a book that when we have for instance a NAND or NOR gate ,the processor doesn't lose energy because we do not have direct current transfer from Vdd to Vss so the processor does not consume energy (apart from some leakage currents). I didn't understand it so much ,so my question is, why we don't have?( if someone could be more specific)

Comment: What is your question execatly? From the static CMOS model of a gate you can see that the only current is the leakage currents.

Comment: My question is , why in cmos model (Nand or Nor for example) the processor doesn't consume energy?(apart from some leakage currents). Why the processor doesn't lose energy? which is the reason?

Comment: Your question is still not clear - write what you expect might happen (but the book, or your experience indicates otherwise). Then you ought to edit the question.

Comment: they answered me ....The second answer is the one that i wanted but thanks for your interest.

Comment: All gates in a processor consume current, some less, some more. And they consume more current while switching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is note quite clearly forumlated, but I guess what the book meant is that typical gate chips are not drawing current at steady state.

This wasn't true on older days (when [TTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor%E2%80%93transistor_logic) ruled the world), but nowadays, this is *almost* true with the CMOS chips. Take a look at a the implementation of a NAND gate, for example:

[image: CMOS NAND]

Whathever the state of the inputs, you see that there is either a path from output to ground (Q3 and Q4), or a path from Vdd to the output (Q1 or Q2), but current can never go from vdd to ground (More details on how CMOS basic functions work can be found [here](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-3/cmos-gate-circuitry/)). Moreover, the inputs being FET gates, the current drawn from the inputs is null.

So, this gate, at steady state, does not draw any current (well, almost).

However, when the output state changes, during the time the FETs change state, there can be a current flowing directly from Vdd to ground (when the FETs are in their linear region, i.e. half-blocking, half-passing). So the more state changes, the more power consumption. Which is why power consumption of processors heavily depends on their frequency of operation.

Now, there is also some tiny leakage current, even when the FETs are blocking. And there is a gate leakage current also, which makes the input currents not exactly null. This leads to a few hundreds of nA wasted, usually.

Answer (score 0):

For sure there is energy loss - each time the gate output or input changes state there is capacitance charged or discharged - this energy can never be recovered so that gets dissipated as heat. Energy loss is therefore proportional to switching frequency.

Comment: i understand it , but what does it mean when the book says:the processor doesn't lose energy because we do not have direct current transfer from Vdd to Vss so the processor does not consume energy (apart from some leakage currents)? Thanks

Comment: Well if both upper and lower "switches" in the CMOS stage are "off" then only leakage current contributes to energy loss. However this is not the case when switching - there can be a small time period when both gates are partially conducting and this consumes power and, of course, there is the charging and discharging of gate capacitance mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8112g.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1a. CMOS output configuration. 1b. Hard-wired switch representation.*

> ... we do not have direct current transfer from Vdd to Vss ...

We do this by ensuring that only the pull-up or pull-down transistor (M1 or M2) is turned on but never both together. Figure 1b might make this a little clearer. If the HI switch is closed the output is pulled high. If the LO switch is closed the output is pulled LO. If both are closed we would have a high current between Vdd and Vss (so we try to avoid it!).

This is true for the static condition but when we switch there is capacitance in the output stage (gates of the transistors, etc.) and the input stages of the following devices. This takes some current to charge and discharge and so power consumption rises with increasing frequency.